# How to allow ftp access to my cell phone?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, ftp

I am on Windows 10 PC that connect my router through Wifi and my android phone also connected to my router through Wifi but when I use file explorer app on the cell phone and enable file transfer I get the address ftp://192.168.0.11:2121 to use on my windows but I get this message:

[image]

I tried to ping 192.168.0.11 and I get normal response so why I can not access my cell phone on this address ?

Comment: Check your firewalls

Comment: I disabled my firewall same problem

Comment: all file manager apps does not work on my Lenovo K4 phone while it work normally on another phone same network and same router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever file explorer app you are using on the phone probably requires a
user name and password to access the exposed shared folder.
Not knowing what app you are using, I cannot help with that information.

There are many other apps that allow sharing data with Android.
Some of the best ones are :

- [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) - allows much more than just file transfer, but the transfer
  is slower.
- The combination of [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=en) on the phone together with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)
  on the PC does file transfers at full speed for the connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different options.  The one I like is called Servers Ultimate Pro.  It lets you run all kinds of servers on your phone, including SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

Install [WiFi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.minimax.wifishare.wififiletransfer) on your android device and run it , it will give you an IP address ; a username , a password and a port , you should allow the port through the firewall .

Open the browser on your PC  , type the IP address  and give your username and the password to connect.

Comment: it work on old phone but my new K4 it does not work !! any ideas ?